# Is it possible to not share static field among instances in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, session, static, field

I have a session scoped controller with a static field and I want it to be limited to that session instance, so I can access the field from other classes inside the session but I don't want it to be shared with other instances that are running in the same JVM.

Is it possible to have a copy of that field for each client in the same JVM?

```
@Controller
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class WebController {
    public static MyClass = new MyClass();

...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the static.

Put that field in a session-scoped bean, and inject it where you need to access it.

Or even simpler, make MyClass itself a session-scoped bean and inject it where you need to access it.

Static fields are evil.

Comment: Thanks, I'll inject the class. I'll also try to avoid static fields from now on